# Check if line is in area

Tags: python, math, 3d

I have given the vector equotation of a line in a three dimensional room and I want to display it. The problem is that I can only show a specific part of the room, which can be moved around. I know the lowest and highest coordinate currently visible. How can I check whether the line has to be shown or in other words whether the line is in the given cube?

What is the best way to do that in Python? As the shown cube and the line should be changeable I don't have exact values on which I could rely. I thought about brute forcing but I think that is quite heavy when having many lines to show.

If you need additional information please ask, I will tell you what I know.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any algorithm for line-box (AABB?) intersection (or [line clipping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_clipping) if you need intersection points).

[Arbitrary example](http://www.3dkingdoms.com/weekly/weekly.php?a=3).
[Another one](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/18436/most-efficient-aabb-vs-ray-collision-algorithms)